# How to update state object within setInterval? [Hooks]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am wondering if anyone has experience merging a state object within a setInterval() function. After trying a few things, I ended up with the solution below, but would appreciate any additional input / tips on how to do this.

---

**Some context:** My codebase started growing, and now I have multiple state variables. I am trying to group the ones that are related into a single object to have more control over the number of renders that occur. One of those state variables is updated within a setInterval() function.

---

I originally had a single state:

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(10)

const start = () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds((seconds) => seconds - 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
```

But I am trying to implement something like:

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState({ seconds: 10, status: 'initial', count: 0 })
```

And I need to update the 'seconds' property of this object. First I attempted something like ... `setTimer({ ...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1000 });` ... which left the interval running, but the 'seconds' were never updated from the subtraction.

Eventually, I implemented the following, which seems to do the trick so far:

```
const start = () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTimer((timer) => (timer = { ...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1000 }));
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is how you supposed to do it, also it equivolents to `setTimer(timer => ({ ...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1000 }));`

Comment: Thank you for confirming! And for providing this simpler form :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction), like in [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-with-immer/) article. And you can set your state more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
const start = () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTimer((timer) => ({ ...timer, seconds: timer.seconds - 1000 }));
  }, 1000);
}
```

Or better would be this:

```
const updatedTimer = {...timer,seconds:timer.seconds - 1000};
const start = () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTimer(updatedTimer);
  }, 1000);
```